# How to open a particular type of file in specific (left or right) editor in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I have two question:

1. Is it possible to associate a file type with an (left or right) editor. For example, I want all my `.html` file to always open in right editor while all my `.css` files to always open in left.
2. How to open a new file in a particular (right or left) editor directly.

Thanks

Comment: 1 - No; 2 - No. Maybe some 3rd party plugin .. but I personally know none.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such features; please vote for [IDEA-84006](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84006), [IDEA-108556](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108556) and linked tickets